# interquartile range from frequency table

Tags: statistics, average

I have attached a word document [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pFk14mHGyzVa33b1RH7OLaGMio1BpmWt)  with the frequency table along with my answer at the answer the textbook gives , only reason I ask is because i'm getting conflicting information on this example my answer is apparently wrong but on another question my method was  used so what is going on?

q)Find the interquartile range for this data.
Ans)

Exemplar answer :

Order the data -0,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4

Q1=(9+1)/4=2.5 which then =2

Q3=3(9+1)/4=7.5 which then =3.5

So 3.5-2 =1.5 is the iqr

My answer:

Firstly find, cumulative frequency

Cf=22

So Q1=(22+1)/4=5.75 which then= game 2

And Q3=3(22+1)/4=17.25= game 8

8-2=6

So interquartile range =6 games 

What answer is right here?

Comment: Well Q1 is supposed to represent the number such that a quarter of the data is below it and three-quarters is above it. To my mind, Q1 should be $2$ and Q3 should be $3$. That is because these value are between the median, $2$ and the smallest and largest values. The inter-quartile range is then $3-2 = 1$.

Comment: @stuartstevenson: Seems you are referring only to the fragment of the data typed into the Question, not the entire dataset of the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have ordered only part of the data. For example, you seem to have ignored the two $1$'s. If I read your link correctly,
the data are $X =$

```
(1,1, 2,2,2,2, 4,4,4, 5,5,5,5, 6,6, 7,7, 8,8,8, 9,9)
```

In that case, R statistical software gives:

```
x = c(1,1, 2,2,2,2, 4,4,4, 5,5,5,5, 6,6, 7,7, 8,8,8, 9,9)
quantile(x)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 1.0  2.5  5.0  7.0  9.0 
IQR(x)
## 4.5
```

Minitab statistical software gives:

```
Variable   N   Mean  StDev  Minimum     Q1  Median     Q3  Maximum    IQR
x         22  5.000  2.582    1.000  2.000   5.000  7.250    9.000  5.250
```

As you can see, results are slightly different. Several different methods of finding quantiles are used in various textbooks
and software programs. At least eight slightly different methods are in
regular use. The practical differences among them disappear when sample sizes
are large. *If your textbook has a clearly stated definition, that's the one
you should use.*

One argument for saying that lower quartile of 2 is as follows: Less than 25% of the $n = 22$ observations are below 2 and less than 25% are above 2. The definition of the median (second or middle
quartile) is fairly standard: Here it is the average of the 11th and 12th
observations, both of which happen to be 5.

R gives the interquartile range (IQR) as $7 - 2.5 = 4.5,$ but Minitab's method gets 5.25, and I think you would get 5 using yet other methods.

Comment: Thankyou very much for  your knowledgeable reply and research ,  in conclusion would you say that my answer of 6 is a suitable estimate ? as I won't be using statistical software which give more accurate answers

Comment: _Use the definition in your text or notes._ I don't think the argument for $Q_3=8$ is especially strong. Seems more like 7 to me. But if you can defend 8 according to the definition you were given, then use it. // Unless you have an unusually open-minded instructor, saying "It's a matter of opinion." (even if true), may not be enthusiastically received. (R chooses one of eight methods as default and allows the user to pick one of the other seven instead with an extra 'argument' to the `quantile` function. In other words the managers of R agree it's a matter of opinion.)

Comment: In R, `quantile(x, type=2)` returns Q1 = 2 and Q3=7, so IQR=5. I believe Method 2 insists all quantiles (including quartiles) be exact numbers from the dataset.

Comment: Yes ok  ,the method in my textbook uses cumulative frequency to find the quartiles so I guess I'll stick to that,why is there so much ambiguity in statistics?

Comment: Pride and stubbornness. (Same as Congress.) Each method has some argument in its favor. Changing methods in major sofware packages (except in R) would require massive re-programming, so none of them is willing to change.

Comment: Yeah that's a good analogy , also I see what you are saying about Q3=7 that definitely makes more sense as  you can't score 17.25 goals :D